# Telerik OpenAccess - Search With Non-Persistent Property

Tags: linq, telerik, openaccess

I'm using Telerik OpenAccess and SQL Server on a project and I need to be able to search by what someone's age will be on a certain date.  The problem that I am running into is that the person's date of birth is stored in one table and the date to compare to is in another table, which prevents me from using a computed column.  They are, however, joined together so that I can calculate the age by creating my own non-persistent property in the partial class like so:

```
public partial class Student
{
    [Telerik.OpenAccess.Transient]
    private int? _ageUponArrival;
    public virtual int? AgeUponArrival
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                var dob = DateTime.Parse(this.StudentProfiles.First().Person.YearOfBirth);
                var programStart = (DateTime)(this.StudentPrograms.First().ProgramStart);
                this._ageUponArrival = programStart.Year - dob.Year;
                if (dob > programStart.AddYears(-(int)(this._ageUponArrival)))
                {
                    (this._ageUponArrival)--;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                this._ageUponArrival = null;
            }

            return _ageUponArrival;
        }
        set { }
    }
}
```

Please ignore how bad the tables are set up, it's something that I inherited and can't change at this point.  The problem with this approach is that the property is not available to search on with Linq.  I know that I could create a view that would do this for me, but I would much rather not have to maintain a view just for this.  Is there any way at all to create a calculated property through Telerik that would be calculated on the db server in such a way as to be searchable?

Comment: It looks like there is a way to do this with Hibernate: [http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#d0e6481](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#d0e6481)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this is not possible at this point. http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/orm/linq-questions/dynamic-query-with-extended-field.aspx